# Accessing bitly api from app

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0, access-token, bit.ly

Hey everyone I was trying to create a URL Shortener android app using bitly api. I have registered my app on bitly and received an API key. I know in order to access bitly's API I need to use an access token which I can get using `OATH2` method and I shouldn't use API key. But I want users to be able to shorten links without creating a bitly account. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried? Please show your code. We can show you how to fix mistakes, but we won't write the code for you from scratch. Note: I have **no experience** with your technology stack, so I don't know the answer. My goal is to help you help other people answer your question. Please take the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages.

Comment: Haven't coded yet. I know how to do it if a user has a bitly account using OATH2.0 but what if an app user doesn't have a bitly account? How to access api for them? I can't use my api key since accessing bitly api with api key is deprecated.

Comment: If you have no code, your question is likely to be closed (I could be wrong). The answer might be "There is no way", since bit.ly specifically requires the use of an API key. This is probably more of a question for bit.ly, not Stack Overflow.